# DateTime object conversion through lambda Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, lambda

I have these two lines

```
weeks_in_field_Sundays = pd.date_range(lastMonday, lastDayField,freq='W')
weeks_in_field_Mondays = weeks_in_field_Sundays(lambda x: datetime.strptime((x - timedelta(days = 6)), "%Y-%m-%d").date())
```

The first one is full with Sunday dates in certain period. I want to calculate all the Mondays of these Sundays, but it says "TypeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object is not callable"
Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I do not know if the other parts are correct, but you should call `weeks_in_field_Sundays.apply(lambda x: ...)` instead of `weeks_in_field_Sundays(lambda x: ...)`

Comment: I tried it but it says 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: `weeks_in_field_Sundays` contains `datetime` objects, not strings. `datetime` objects have no format so there's nothing for `strptime` to parse

Comment: And, as the error says, `pd.date_range` returns an index of datetime values, not a series of strings

Answer (score 1):

From your code I estimate that you want the Monday before the given Sunday, even if it is not in the given range:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
sun = pd.date_range("2022-01-01", "2023-01-01",freq='W')
mon = [(s-dt.timedelta(days=6)).date() for s in sun]
```

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) returns an index of datetime values, not a series of strings. You can use that index to create a dataframe and add series to it:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

weeks_in_field_Sundays = pd.date_range('2023-06-26', '2023-10-31',freq='W')

df=pd.DataFrame(index=weeks_in_field_Sundays)
df['Mondays']=df.index- timedelta(days = 6)
```

You can add the index itself as a series

```
df['Sundays']=df.index
```

This produces

```
            Mondays     Sundays
2023-07-02  2023-06-26  2023-07-02
2023-07-09  2023-07-03  2023-07-09
2023-07-16  2023-07-10  2023-07-16
2023-07-23  2023-07-17  2023-07-23
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you're trying to call the `weeks_in_field_Sundays` object as a function. To calculate what you want, you can use the DatetimeIndex object's to_series method to convert it to a pandas Series, and then apply a lambda function. See [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-datetimeindex-to_series/).

`weeks_in_field_Sundays.to_series().apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime((x - timedelta(days = 6)), "%Y-%m-%d").date())`